# PHP DateTime from integer values

Tags: php

If have `$day`, `$month`, and `$year` as integer values and want to create a `DateTime` object in PHP 7.
Creating a string representation to let it parse into a date, such as:

```
$date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
```

looks quite ridiculous to me. I tried to set the date after creation, such as:

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setDate($year, $month, $day);
```

but since `new DateTime()` uses the current timestamp the time part of the object is still set to the current time (instead of *00:00:00*). So I'd have to set the time value as well, what seems inefficcient to me as well:

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setDate($year, $month, $day)->setTime(0, 0);
```

**What is therefore the best (i.e. most performant) way to create a new `DateTime` instance for a date when I already have day, month and year as integer values?**

**UPDATE**

For some users seem to misinterpret my question: I'm asking rather for a performant than for an aesthetic solution. ;-)

Yes `new DateTime("$year-$month-$day")` is short and nice, but is it the recommended way to let PHP parse a date string I already have split to its int values?

Comment: You must love insanely succinct code to feel that $date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day"); is too onerous. If someone beats that, I will be impressed.

Comment: *"looks quite ridiculous to me"* — That's PHP for ya. ;) There's indeed no real alternative.

Comment: Take a look into Carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @Kurt I take this to mean that in e.g. Python or Javascript, the equivalent constructor takes ints as separate arguments. Compared to that, concatenating ints into a string which are then parsed back into ints is indeed somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: _“So I'd have to set the time value as well, what seems inefficcient to me as well”_ - seems a bit “complaining on a high comfort level” to begin with to me … Use `(new DateTime('00:00'))->setDate($year, $month, $day)` then maybe, if that pleases you more on an aesthetical level, by having the time specified at the point of construction of the DateTime object already …?

Comment: @CBroe It may not be a big deal for seasoned PHP programmers, but if you're used to languages where the date constructor accepts individual ints, this is something of a bizarre API. I find the condescending tone here worrisome.

Comment: @deceze I am not trying to say it is an ideal implementation, and there should be a static constructor for this use case, but its already pretty tight and readable.

Comment: @deceze "CBroe It may not be a big deal for seasoned PHP programmers, but if you're used to languages where the date constructor accepts individual ints, this is something of a bizarre API" Same logic can be used in reverse. But again, I agree with you an int constructor should be supported.

Comment: @deceze didn’t mean that to be condescending, but it really seems like a _very_ minor issue … PHP has its peculiarities, for sure, and lots of them. But that’s just something anyone working with that language will have to accept.

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting the question? I thought "what ist the best way to create a new `DateTime`?" is a valid question? If "use the string constructor and let PHP parse it" is the best way then so be it.

Comment: Regarding your last statement, what is your concern?

Comment: @revo My concern is, that there might be a more performant way to create a DateTime if I already have the date values (day, month, year) as int values than to create a string from it that PHP has to parse again and split to its int particles. ;-)

Comment: My PC needs 3.4 seconds on average to create one million `DateTime` instances that way. As a comparison, switching to `DateTime::createFromFormat()` reduces time to 3.2 second and switching to Unix times and `mktime()` brings it down to 3.1 seconds. If performance is your concern, be sure to benchmark different solutions in your own server, but also make sure you have enough dates to make it worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the concern, converting integers into a string which is then parsed by some automagic as some matching date format does seem somewhere between inefficient and insane to instantiate `DateTime` objects from what are already integers. Alas, there's no [alternative constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in standard PHP `DateTime` classes that would offer any alternative.

Personally I always feel icky letting PHP auto-parse any sort of date string to hope it gets it right, so I'd actually prefer the more explicit alternative:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "$year-$month-$day")
```

But that is mostly personal preference, `new DateTime("$year-$month-$day")` should accomplish exactly the same thing as long as your variables actually contain the values you think they do.

If you're only after a conversion to UNIX timestamps, there's [`mktime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) which accepts explicit integer arguments, albeit it in a weird order:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)
```